# C++: All elements in vector of struct pointers updated when adding a new struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to code a relatively simple program where I can add `struct`s to a vector in C++, edit them and read from them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct a {
    int e;
    string msg;
};

int main()
{
    vector<a*> lists;
    for (int f = 0; f < 4; ++f) {
        a b;
        b.e = f;
        b.msg = "J";
        lists.push_back(&b);
    }
    for (auto g : lists) {
        cout << g->e << g->msg << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Initially, I tried using `vector<struct>`, but after discovering that you can't edit `struct`s that way, I turned it into a vector that holds pointers to `struct`.

I expected the code above to produce:

```
0J
1J
2J
3J
```

but it ends up producing:

```
3
3
3
3
```

After some examination, I have determined that every time I add a new element to my vector, all the other elements are updated, becoming exact copies of the new element.

If I move the second for loop into the first for loop, I get:

```
0J
1J
1J
2J
2J
2J
3J
3J
3J
3J
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: `vector<struct>` should be `vector<a>` right? It's a typo?

Comment: You do not have a vector of structs.  You have a vector of pointers.  Once the `a b;` goes out of scope, it is destructed.  Accessing it through a pointer after it is destructed is undefined behavior.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The vector<struct> is just an example. My actual program has a ```vector<a*>``` in it.

Comment: `struct` is an unfortunate example. Did you mean `a`? What about [this](https://godbolt.org/z/b967hq)? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Hint: Dont' use `*` pointers until you're really getting to very large projects.

Comment: "_after discovering that you can't edit structs that way,_" - In what way? Your struct is wide open for editing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your code example includes a regular vector of structs, which doesn't let me edit the structs later on.

Comment: @MSuccessor Of course it does. What are you talking about really? Show an example where you store stuff in a `vector<a>` and are not able to edit the `a`s in the vector.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I misread the output data. Oops.

Comment: @MSuccessor I think I have an idea of what you do wrong (but I have to guess since you haven't shown the code where you try):. Are you perhaps updating _copies_ of the elements instead of using references to the elements in the vector? Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/f3GEuS) of how you can update.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you mean, I once had the same problem. I figured out that the reason why this happens is because the object is being created in the for loop, so the information inside `vector` points to the same memory address, therefore showing the same information for all *objects* inside of it  (be careful, you don't have a vector of structs, you have a vector of pointers).

The way I solved that anyway: I created a function which contained the definition of the new object, the for loop would call the function, so the memory adress which it's pointing to would be different every time. (There is probably a more efficient way to solve this but that worked).

It would look something like this:

```
struct StructName{
   //any attribs
}

StructName* ObjectFactory
{
   StructName *newobject = new StructName;
   return newobject;
}
```

Now it should point to different memory addresses on every iteration, if a vector of pointers is what you are looking for.